# UITableViewCells are overlapping

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uitableview, uilabel

I have a UITableViewCell which detailTextLabel causes the cells frame to be dependant on its size.

My code for that is this:

cell for row at index method

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"Rights";
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
            cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self getItemForKey:kRights];
            cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
            cell.detailTextLabel.font = cell.textLabel.font;
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:54.0f/255.0f green:54.0f/255.0f blue:54.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
            CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(310.0f, MAXFLOAT);
            CGSize labelSize = [[cell.detailTextLabel text] sizeWithFont:[cell.detailTextLabel font] constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
            cell.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 310, labelSize.height);
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

Height for row at index method

```
 if (indexPath.row == 3){
                NSString *text = [self getItemForKey:kRights];
                CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(310.0f, MAXFLOAT);
                CGSize labelSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]
                                    constrainedToSize:constraintSize 
                                        lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
                return labelSize.height+11;
            }
```

However, if the size of the label is too big, the cells overlap each other. Please could you tell me how I can prevent this?

Here is an image to show you my problem:

http://img689.imageshack.us/i/screenshot2011042102520.png/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you just forget, in the height for row at index method, to account for the rest of the content of the cell?  You are adding 11 points to the height of the detailTextLabel.  It doesn't look like that's enough.  Running [@"Rights" sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]] returns a height of 19.  So, you would need that much to account for the textLabel height, plus any space you leave between textLabel & detail, plus top and bottom margins within the cell, plus any other content of the cell.

Also, from your screen shot, it seems like you might have some overlapping of the content within this particular cell. That could be a result of the frame you're setting for the detailTextLabel:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 310, labelSize.height);
```

You set the origin of the frame at (0, 0), that is, the top left corner of the cell.  That would make the detailTextLabel overlap the textLabel for the cell.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I set the frame to this: cell.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake( 0, cell.textLabel.frame.origin.y+5, 310, labelSize.height); but it hasn't made a difference. also, the 11 points are for for coverage of the textlabel and the rest of the content.

Comment: The new frame looks right.  The word "Rights", i.e. the textLabel, seems to be overlapping some other text.  Is the text it's overlapping the detailTextLabel, or is it content from a different cell?

Comment: I ran  [@"Rights" sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]]  & it returned a height of 19.0.  That would imply that you need more than the 11 points to cover for the textLabel.

Comment: its content from another cell.

Comment: So, it's possible that the problem is in the row height.  Did you try increasing it?  For the row height, maybe try adding at least 24 to labelSize.height.  That would be 19 for the textLabel and 5 more for the space you left between the two labels in the new detailTextLabelFrame.

Comment: I just tried that, and it did not work. I tried cell.clipsToBounds = YES; and it worked, but the textLabel had a lot of text hidden.

Comment: So, that confirms that the detailTextLabel is not fitting within the cell.  Try adding more than 24 to the row height.  Is more of the detailTextLabel now visible? If it is, then the problem is here & it's solved by increasing the row height.  If not, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: thanks, I fixed it. Please add some information from the above comments to the answer, and I will accept it :)